# Playing song more smoothly on oboe

Tags: technique, practice, oboe

I have to play John Rutter's [A Gaelic Blessing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Gaelic_Blessing) but I am finding it a little hard to play smoothly. I can play it through with good fingering but I am having trouble with the dynamics and sometimes I stop and I am out of breath. Any pointers?

Comment: This is the kind of thing you should ask your teacher. It's almost impossible to get very far on the oboe without a good teacher.

Comment: Are you managing to support your sound from the diaphragm?